# Addition of Two Numbers represented by Linked List nodes

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm preparing for an interview. The question I got is: Two numbers are represented by a linked list, where each node contains a single digit.The digits are stored in reverse oder, such that the 1's digit is at the head of the list. Write a function that adds the two numbers and returns the sum as a linked list.
The suggested answer adds each digits individually and keeps a "carry" number. For example, if the first digits of the two numbers are "5" and "7". The algorithm records "2" in the first digit of resulting sum and keeps "1" as a "carry" to add to 10th digit of result.
However, my solution is to traverse the two linked lists and translate them into two integers. Then I add the numbers and translate sum to a new linked list. Wouldn't my solution be more straight forward and efficient?
Thanks!

Comment: SO is not place for you to get interview questions answered. What have you done ?

Comment: Have you written both out for comparison?

Answer (score 1):

While your solution may be more straightforward, I don't think it's actually more efficient.

I'm assuming the "correct" algorithm is something like this:

1. pop the first element of both lists
2. Add them together (with the carry if there is one) and make a new node using the ones digit
3. Pass the carry (dividing the sum by 10 to get the actual thing to carry) and repeat 1) and 2), with each successive node being pointed to by the previous one.

The main things I see when I'm comparing your algorithm with that one is:

1. In terms of memory, you want to create two `BigInteger`s to store intermediate values (I'm assuming you're using `BigInteger` or some equivalent `Object` to avoid the constraints of an `int` or `long`), on top of the final linked list itself. The original algorithm doesn't use more than a couple of `int`s to do intermediate calculations, and so in the long run, the original algorithm actually uses less memory.
2. You're also suggesting that you do all of your arithmetic using the `BigInteger`s, rather that in `int`s. Although it's possible that `BigInteger` is really optimized to the point where it isn't much slower than primitive operations, I highly doubt that calling `BigInteger#add` is faster than doing the `+` operation on `int`s.

Also, some more food for thought. Suppose you didn't have something handy like `BigInteger` to store arbitrarily large integers. Then you're going to have to have some way to store arbitrarily large integers for your algorithm to work properly. After that, you basically need a way to add arbitrarily large integers to add arbitrarily large integers, and you end up with a problem where you either have to do something like the original algorithm *anyway*, or you end up using a completely different representation in a subroutine (yikes).

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming by "integer" you mean `int`.)

Your solution does not scale beyond numbers that can fit in an `int`, whereas the original solution is only limited by the amount of available memory.

As far as efficiency is concerned, there is nothing about your solution that would make it more efficient than the original.

Comment: He could just as easily use a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is more straightforward to describe, certainly - and an argument might be made in certain situations that the readability of the code your solution would produce would be preferable, when working with large teams.

However, most of the time - their suggested answer is a lot more memory efficient, and probably more CPU-efficient.

You're suggesting going through the first linked-list, storing it as a number (+1 store). Going through the second, storing it as a number (+1 store). Adding the 2 numbers, saving the result (+1 store). Converting this number into a linked list, and saving it (+1 store)

Their solution involves going through the first and second linked list, while writing to the third, and storing it as a new one (+1 store)

This is a +1 store, vs. your +4 store. This might seem like not much, but if we were to try and add n pairs of numbers at the same time (on a distributed system or something), you're looking at 4n stores, rather than just n stores. Which could be a big deal.